# Irobot Create 2 installation issues

Tags: ros, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I robot create 2 driver installation confusion
Installed driver for Irobot Create 2 from here. I am a little stuck though. I was expecting a GUI or a place to input commands and not really sure what to do next. https://github.com/MirkoFerrati/irobotcreate2ros

I run

rosrun irobotcreate2 irobotcreate2

and get:

[ INFO] [1466316801.213298743]: Roomba for ROS 2.01
[ INFO] [1466316801.350324458]: Connected to Roomba.
[ INFO] [1466316801.451156961]: Waiting for roomba sensors
Sending OPCode: �
Sending OPCode: �
Sending OPCode: �
Sending OPCode: �

The tutorial says:

rosrun irobotcreate2 irobotcreate2

to run the basic software and have access to the following topics:

/battery
/bumper
/buttons
/cliff
/cmd_vel
/digit_leds
/ir_bumper
/ir_character
/leds
/mode
/odom
/play_song
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/song
/tf
/wheel_drop
you can read sensors (/battery, /buttons, /bumper, ...) and send commands (/cmd_vel, ...).

No idea what to do with these commands without a UI. Any help would be much obliged. First time ROS user..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237452/irobot-create-2-installation-issues/) by [singularity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27219/singularity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I agree that the package seems to be not documented enough, it does say you can send velocity commands by `/cmd_vel`. I suggest you go through [this generic tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) once again, and replace the topic name appropriately to work with Create2.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0